# How to fix wrong return statement for last test variable?

Tags: python

Write a function called venue() that takes two parameters. Your function should read the value in the string parameter. If the string == "party" and number < 10, function should return "Have it at home." If string == "party" and number >= 10, function should return "Better rent an event place." Any other value should return "hire an event planner."

```
def venue(s, n):
    if s == "party" and n < 10:
        return "Have it at home"
    elif s == "party" and n >= 10:
        return "Better rent an event place"
    else:
        return "Hire an event planner"

a = venue("party", 9)
b = venue("party", 20)
c = venue("party", 100)
```

I expect the last return value to be "hire an event planner", but I get "better rent an event place"

Comment: But, party, 100 is party and n >= 10.  right?

Comment: How about: `c = venue("wedding", 100)`?

Comment: Yes...your code is correct.  Your test data and/or your assumptions of what is correct behavior is what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `c` matches the second condition, it returns `"Better rent an event place"`

To fix this, you can change the string value of `c` to be something different such as `"event"`

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote in your loop that

```
if s == "party" and n < 10:

    return "Have it at home"

elif s == "party" and n >= 10:

    return "Better rent an event place"

else:

    return "Hire an event planner"
```

which means that, if there's any n value that is lager than or equal to 10, the return would be "Better rent an event place". However, if the n value is other than any value smaller than, equal to or larger than 10, the return would be "Hire an event planner", which is not possible in normal cases.

If possible, then try to change something in the variables or the symbols in the loop.

Hope this helps.